# Is the CSS [attribute="value"] Selector unnecessary?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm taking one of the edX classes on CSS and they've included:

```
[class*='example'] { background-color: orange; }
```

in the CSS stylesheet. Not familiar with that type of an attribute, so I looked it up. Essentially it just adds a style to anything using a specific class [(or id), depending on the specific attribute]. Why wouldn't you just add:

```
background-color: orange;
```

to the appropriate class, or id, and be done with it? Is there a significant purpose to this type of attribute that I'm missing?

Comment: There are more attributes than just `id` and `class`. I’ve seen it most commonly used in the context of `input[type="text"]` to select a specific type of input

Comment: If you're not sure if you need it, you probably don't. Whenever you don't have to use these so called regex selector avoid them. They are pretty expensive render-wise.

Comment: @TylerH This is not a duplicate. The question you linked is asking if something is possible, my question is asking about the usefulness of selectors. Two entirely different questions. Furthermore, I have long since accepted a very thorough answer.

Comment: @elbrant The answers in the target question linked above answer this question, too, which is what the duplicate function is for. That you've accepted an answer here is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` in `[class*='example']` is a selector that retrieves all elements that contains `example` in the class-name and not just elements with the class-name `example`.

So **`[class*='example']`** will target all of the following:

```
<div class="iamanexample"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="whereisyourexample"></div>
```

Whereas **`.example`** or **`[class='example']`** will only target the second element `<div class="example"></div>` from the above three.

---

Other attribute selectors in CSS includes the:

**`~` selector:** This selector retrieves all elements whose targeted attribute's value contains the exact queried value. This selector can include multiple values in the form of a *whitespace-separated* list of words.

**`|` selector:** This selector retrieves all elements whose targeted attribute's value is exactly the queried value or begins with queried value immediately followed by a hyphen.

**`^` selector:** This selector retrieves all elements whose targeted attribute's value starts with the queried value.

**`$` selector:** This selector retrieves all elements whose targeted attribute's value ends with the queried value.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example and explanation in the code comments on how each of the above selector works:

```css
/* all elements whose abc value contains "ment" */
div[abc*="ment"] { font-weight: 700; }

/* all elements whose abc value is exactly "element-1" */
div[abc~="element-1"] { color: blue; }

/* all elements whose abc value is exactly "element" or begins with "element" immediately followed by a hyphen */
div[abc|="element"] { background-color: green; }

/* all elements whose abc value starts with "x" */
div[abc^="x"] { background-color: red; }

/* all elements whose abc value ends with "x" */
div[abc$="x"] { background-color: yellow; }

div { margin: 5px 0px; }
```

```html
<div abc="element-1">Hello World!</div>
<div abc="element-2">Hello World!</div>

<div abc="xElement1">Hello World!</div>
<div abc="xElement2">Hello World!</div>

<div abc="element1x">Hello World!</div>
<div abc="element2x">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: This description of `~=` is incorrect. The selector can only specify one word, but it matches every element whose target attribute, when interpreted as a list of whitespace-separated words, contains that word. For example, `<div title="foo bar baz">` is matched by `div[title~="baz"]`. On the other hand, `[foo~="a b"]` never matches: No single word will be equal to "a b" (because single words don't contain spaces).